# MutableList to MutableMap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist, mutablemap

I have a mutable list of objects that belong to custom class Expense.
Class Expense has following attributes:

- amount
- category

I want to create a mutable map by iterating through the list above and the result should be as follows:

category_1 : sum of all amounts that had category_1 as category

category_2 : sum of all amounts that had category_2 as category

...

I am looking for a one-liner if possible. Kotlin idiomatic code.

This is what I have so far:

```
listOfExpenses.associateTo(expensesByCategory) {it.category to it.amount}
```

I need the last part: it.amount to somehow be a sum of all the amounts belonging to a certain category.

listOfExpenses is the list of Expense objects, expensesByCategory is the map I want to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is more than one line but it does what you need

```
val expensesByCategory = listOfExpenses
    .groupBy { it.category }
    .mapValues { it.value.sumBy { it.amount } }
```

Comment: Niceee! :) This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Follow up question: what if amount was a Double and not an Int ?
I am getting some type mismatch, I think sumBy is expecting Int?

Comment: Nvm found the sumByDouble function :) Still a follow up question: If one was to read this code statement in English how would that go?

Comment: I dont understand the question. Function names are descriptive.